# Cookies detection in php using session_start()

Tags: php, cookies

I want to know whether user has blocked cookies. I have googled for the solution in php. I have found the solutions to create a cookie and redirect to another page and then check the cookie. When I started thinking I have came across this solution

I am not sure if this method is harmful or not secure. Can anyone explain me if this method can be used or not

```
<?php session_start();

if(!isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) echo 'cookies are disabled, set cookies';
```

I have read `session_start()` creates a cookie on clients system to keep track of clients browser which is sent through headers for every http request and its key is `PHPSESSID`

If user blocks cookies in his browser `session_start()`  cannot create the cookie file with the key `PHPSESSID` nor the headers are sent.

So understanding this I have found the above solution and it works, tested on FF, Chrome, >=IE8.

Let me know if this is method have any downsides. Thanks

Comment: A cookie that has been issued is not available until the next request of the client as it is sent within the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but it won't work. You can use cookies and check if they exist only if you refresh page / go to another url.

I' tested it to make sure in Firefox and Internext Explorer and I get:

```
cookies are disabled, set cookies
```

when I visit site and when I refresh it, I get no info so as you see this solution doesn't work at all.